# Exporting a single feature out of featureCollection as shapefile in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, geometry, export, features

Does any one know, how to export a single feature out of featureCollection in Google Earth Engine?

I am using below code to export every features separately. The fetureCollection has 33 different features which represents different 33 geometry of regions. I want to get those geometry separately as shapefile.

The blow code gives me an error in task section: Error: Invalid argument: 'collection' must be a FeatureCollection. So, tried to get the sub_region(in the code) as `ee.FeatureCollection` instead of `ee.Feature` , but I am still getting same error.

```
var refReg = ee.FeatureCollection("users/username/referenceRegions");

var referenceRegions={
  0:'NTP',1:'STP',2:'ETP',3:'WIO',4:'CAR',5:'NAU',6:'NEB',7:'NEU',8:'SAF',
  9:'SAH',10:'SAU',11:'SSA',12:'TIB',13:'WAF',14:'WAS',15:'WNA',16:'WSA',
  17:'ALA',18:'AMZ',19:'CAM',20:'CAS',21:'CEU',22:'CGI',23:'CNA',24:'EAF',
  25:'EAS',26:'ENA',27:'MED',28:'NAS',29:'ARC',30:'SAS',31:'SEA',32:'ANT'
};

var region_list = refReg.toList(refReg.size());

var reg_size = refReg.size().getInfo();

for (var i = 0; i<reg_size;i++){
   var sub_region = ee.Feature(region_list.get(i));

   Export.table.toDrive({
   collection: sub_region,
   description:referenceRegions[i],
   folder:"GEE_Features",
   fileFormat: "SHP",
   })
}
```

If you see the below image, the FeatureCollection `refReg` has all these 33 regions, I want these regions to export individually.

[image]

Thanks for the help!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your asset ID doesn't look correct, so I cannot try it. But just by looking at it, everything look OK except for when you pass `sub_region` as your `Export.table.toDrive()` `collection`. That property must be a feature collection. Try with this:

```
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ee.FeatureCollection([sub_region]),
  description: referenceRegions[i],
  folder: "GEE_Features",
  fileFormat: "SHP",
})
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it worked :)